# TypeError at /cart/cheese-grits/ update_cart() missing 1 required positional argument: 'qty'

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I am trying to add more than one of the same item to a cart. I have been able to add one of each item to the cart, but when I tried to implement a quantity function, I get this error.
When I was using a loop that made buttons, when I clicked them it would add one of that item to the order. I want to be able to add multiple of the same item. Thank you

Views.py:

```
def view(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        the_id = None
    if the_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        products = Product.objects.all()

        context = {"cart": cart,
                    "products": products
                }
    else:
        context = {"empty": True,
                "products": products
                }


    template = "mis446/home.html"

    return render(request, template, context)

def update_cart(request, slug, qty):
    try:
        qty = request.GET.get('qty')
        update_qty = True
    except:
        qty = None
        update_qty = False


    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)


    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass

    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart = cart, product=product)
    if created:
        print ("yeah")

    if update_qty and qty:
        if int(qty) == 0:
            cart_item.delete()
        else:
            cart_item.quantity = qty
            cart_item.save()
    else:
        pass
    # if not cart_item in cart.items.all():
    #   cart.items.add(cart_item)
    # else:
    #   cart.items.remove(cart_item)

    new_total = 0.00
    for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
        line_total = item.product.price * item.quantity
        new_total += line_total
    request.session['items_total'] = cart.products.all().count()    
    cart.total = new_total
    cart.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

urls.py:

```
  url(r'^cart/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', carts_views.update_cart, name='update_cart'),

    url(r'^cart/$', carts_views.view, name='cart')
```

models.py:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', null= True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    line_total = models.DecimalField(default = 10.99, max_digits = 1000, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        try:
            return str(self.cart.id)
        except:
            return self.product.title

class Cart(models.Model):
    # items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, null=True, blank = True)
    # products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Cart id: %s" %(self.id)
```

html:

```
    <label for="order"><h2 style= "color:#EAEAEA"><u>Order Details</u></h2></label>
<table class='table' style= "color:#EAEAEA">
  <thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td></td>
      <td>Total: {{ cart.total }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
{% for item in cart.cartitem_set.all %}
<tr><td>{{ item.product }}</td><td>{{ item.product.price }}</td><td>
  <td>{{ item.quantity}}</td><td><a href='{% url "update_cart" item.product.slug  %}?qty=0'>Remove</a> </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>



{% for product in products %}

<div>
   <br>
    <button class ="btn btn-info btn-md" class ='pull-right'> <a href='{% url "update_cart" product.slug %}?qty=10' style= "color:#EAEAEA">{{ product.name }}:  ${{ product.price }}</a></button>


 <br>

<form class = 'pull-right' method ='GET' action='{% url "update_cart" product.slug %}?qty=12'>


<input name = 'qty' type = 'number'/>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'Add to cart'/>
</form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: check the url in the browser when you click the update button, I think the problem is there

Comment: I don't really know how to fix that. It inputs the slug into the url for some reason

Comment: try change `?qty=0` to `&qty=0` because if the url have multiple arguments it can't have 2 of question mark, in your case the slug is the first argument so may be its look like this `your_update_url?slug?qty=0`